# Disable [INFO] log in cloudwatch to reduce IMR cost of AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights, cost-management

How do I filter out [**INFO**] log in **cloudwatch** in aws so that I only keep the [**ERROR**] logs to reduce **IMR** as it is occupying majority of our IMR cost? We are getting many request logs in an interval of 1 sec. How can I disable the INFO log from my log group? Any help would mean a lot.
Thanks.

Comment: What does IMR mean?